# Convergence of Series correctly determined? (Quotient and Alternating Series Criterions)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

The following pictures contains three exercises about series that I resolved and would like to know if they're correct. I tried resolving them with Symbolab, but the app solves the exercises with other criterions and would like to know if they way I worked them are correct.

I've attached two pictures, the first one is the exercise labeled 22, which I solved with the Alternating Series criterion:

[Exercise 22 - Alternating Series Criterion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBrZa.jpg)

And the other one contains two exercises - 68 and 24 which I solved with the Quotient (Ratio?) Criterion and the Alternating Series Criterion, respectively:

[Exercises 68, 24 - Quotient and Alternating Series criterions, respectively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N42Zu.jpg)

I appreciate any input and feedback but also apologize for the Spanish. However, I'm glad that math is an universal language.

Oh, btw... **My conclusion was that all three series converged.**

If missed important information or did something wrong please let me know.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ex. 22**, the alternating series test told you the alternate series converges, but you still have to check if this an "absolute convergence" or a "conditional convergence".  (not sure they are called that, I'm brazilian and not used to writing math in english, hehe).

**ex 68**, looks right! sorry about first answer! *edited this.*

**ex 24**, same as 22, you apply the alternate series test just right, but gotta go until the end and test the absolute series to check if it's an absolute or a conditional convergence.

(Obs.: To test the absolute series, you will ignore the alternating factor on those series [(-1) to the n, n+1, etc] and treat them as if they were regular positive series, using one of the usual tests (ratio, comparison, root, etc.)

Comment: Regarding **ex 22**, I expanded **3^n+1** as **3^n * 3**. Regarding **ex 68,22**, we haven't gotten to the point of learning about absolute or conditional convergence. Does this mean that so far as testing for convergence, they seem good?

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I see, my friend. If the point was just to use the alternate test, they seem to be correct to my viewing! Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have a good night!